# Fail to tunnel between two Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, ipsec

I running 2 Solaris 10 box and trying to tunnel them up through Internet.
1 at the hosting site while the other sitting in my office.

```
ifconfig ip.tun0 plumb
ifconfig ip.tun0 192.168.1.207 192.168.1.239 tsrc 175.139.xxx.xxx tdst 202.187.xxx.xxx
ifconfig: Failure: ip.tun0: Cannot assign requested address
```

I able to execute the command at the hosting box but fail to execute at the one in my office. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local office server: 175.139.xxx.xxx

Is that the actual ip address of the local office server?  or is that the publicly visible NAT address of your office network?

The `tsrc` address needs to be the servers local ipv4 address, not the office NAT address.

Note that this should only be changed on this side of the tunnel.  The remote server will still use the NAT address as the `tsdt` address.

Comment: It's a NAT address. So the command will be `ifconfig ip.tun0 192.168.1.207 192.168.1.239 tsrc 192.168.1.207 tdst 202.187.xxx.xxx`?

Comment: Yes.  Although, you'll probably need to use a different address scheme for the tunnel.  like 10.1.1.1/30 and 10.1.1.2/30, then on the remote host, you could add a static route for the 192.168.1 network pointing to the local side 10-net address of the tunnel.